# Save a push notification that isn't opened

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. I'm also saving these notifications locally. But I noticed if I'm at the home screen and don't open the notification, this function never gets called, and I can't save the notification. Any ideas?

Comment: That's as per the design and documentation. You need to change your plan about how you manage that data (and possibly what you're using it for)

Comment: So I can't do anything with the notification unless it's opened?

Comment: Unless your app is registered to handle it in the background before presentation and the notification contains the appropriate flag

Comment: you could use a “silent” notification (add to payload json key/value content-available=1), see more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` instead of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. See [official documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:):

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Also make sure to enable "remote notifications background mode", like stated in the documentation. Edit `Info.plist` and check the "Enable Background Modes" and "Remote notifications" check boxes:

[image]